# Probability that North and South have all the Queens between them

Tags: probability

> In a bridge game what is the probability that North and South have all the Queens between them?

My professor has repeatedly stated that the answer is:

$\frac{{{48}\choose{13}} {{35}\choose{13}}} {{{52}\choose{13}} {{39}\choose{13}}}$

But I don't understand where he gets the $48$ and $35$ from.

Comment: Your professor is looking East and West and seeing no queens.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stephen that the above is the probability of two hands not having any queens.
$$\frac{\binom{48}{13}\binom{35}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}}$$
Of the 48 cards remaining after you ignore the 4 queens chose 13 for the first non-queen hand.  Then, of the 35 remaining cards, excluding the 4 queens and 13 cards held by the first hand, choose 13 for the second non-queen hand.

I prefer to count Sample Space as follows:

$$\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}
=\binom{52}{26}\binom{26}{13,13}=\binom{52}{26}\frac{26!}{13!13!}$$

Interpreting the middle as, of the 52 cards choose 26 to go in the two hands.  Now partition those 26 cards into 13 cards and 13 cards respectively.

For Two hands of 13 containing the 4 queens between them.  There are 5 cases that this could happen:

A has 0 queens, B has 4 queens 
A has 1 queens, B has 3 queens
A has 2 queens, B has 2 queens
A has 3 queens, B has 1 queens
A has 4 queens, B has 0 queens

so I would interpret the probability of two hands having all queens between them as.

$$\frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{22}\binom{22}{13,9}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{22}\binom{22}{12,10}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{22}\binom{22}{11,11}+\binom{4}{3}
\binom{48}{22}\binom{22}{10,12}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{22}\binom{22}{9,13}}{\binom{52}{26}\binom{26}{13,13}}$$

Note that the terms in the numerator are symmetric.

Comment: Sorry that none of my MathJax showed up.  I will try to redo it later.

Comment: \\( and \\) are not used to format MathJax on this site; two $\$\$$'s are.